# What Regular Expression can I use to extract part of a URL?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm having problems creating the Regex needed to extract a portion of a URL in Big Query.

Hi - I'm looking to extract the **part1** section of the URL below:

https://host.name.com/part1/part2

Please can someone advise the correct Regex to use.

I've tried the following, but only returns host.name.com

```sql
REGEXP_EXTRACT(page_url, r"//([^//]*)") as Part1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the subpart after the host part:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(page_url, r"://[^/]*/([^/]*)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OIkeVY/1).

*Details*:

- `://` - a `://` substring
- `[^/]*` - zero or more chars other than `/` (no need to double this character in any pattern)
- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than `/`

Comment: That's solved the problem. Thanks Wiktor...much appreciated!

Comment: @Gary You are welcome. The point is to always find a pattern that is generic enough to match the *context* (here, `://[^/]*/`, that matches all the host part with the leading protocol suffix) and then capture within parentheses the main pattern part.